# How to mount my macOS volume on my Linux through network

Tags: linux, debian, mac-osx, nfs

I have a Linux Debian 10 and a MacOS Monterey system on the same local area network.

As my macOS only have 8GB of ram, I would like to use my Linux system to do coding on the mac, using a mounted network volume from macOS to Linux.

This way, I am able to use my IDE on linux, and directly edit files on the mac, so mac can re-trigger my react-native app compilation.

So far, I have found https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse that I already compiled and installed on my Linux.

How can I now create a shared volume on the mac, and mount it to my linux?

Answer (score 0):

OSX has two built in disk sharing options: SMB and NFS3. The fist place to start is the `Sharing` option under `System Preferences`. Che the official documentation from Apple:

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-file-sharing-on-mac-mh17131/mac